# What is the way in which an audio signal is "cleaned"?

Tags: signal-analysis, noise-cancellation, decomposition

I was studying how signals can be "decompose" with the Frequency domain analysis and Fourier transforms; I have also read that through these actions it is possible to clean the signals from the noises, separating the unwanted frequencies from the main signal. So I was wondering how this procedure works, in a practical way, for example to clean up wind noise signals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> for example to clean up wind noise signals?

Wind noise is a relatively good approximation of *white noise*, i.e. noise that has the same power at all frequencies.

So, by *filtering* the signal with a filter that only lets through the frequencies mostly used by the kind of sounds you're interested in (e.g., speech, or birdsong, or wind turbine buzz, which would all have significant content at different frequencies), you suppress a significant amount of the noise power.

Anyway, this means you need to learn what filtering is! You can do that in the frequency domain, as well, but need to take special care (because you can only transform audio into the frequency domain in "chunks", and thus you get effects on the ends of these chunks).

Comment: Ok thanks, so I'll try to study something about filters